# Can I make this request more efficient using index?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

I have this bean/table "Userinfo" with columns id, username, and twitchChannel.
For most userinfo the twitchChannel column will be null. I'm going through every userinfo entity in the table and search the column twitchChannel, if the column is not null I put the twitchChannel in an array.

this is what my request looks like:

```
"SELECT ui FROM Userinfo ui WHERE ui.iduserinfo=:id"
```

It is very inefficient because I'm going through every single entity even those which have a null twitchChannel and I'm not interested in those.

This is java but I commented every line so it's easy to understand for those who don't know it.

```
    while (true) { // I'm going through the table in an infinite loop
        int id = 0; //id that is incremented for searches
        Userinfo ui;  // this will be an object that will hold the result of my query
        do {
            ui = ups.getUserInfo(id); // this execute the query I posted above
            id++; //incrementing id for next search
            if (ui.getTwitch() != null) {  // if the search didn't return null
                twitchChannels.add(ui.getTwitch());   // put my twitch in an array
            }
        } while (ui != null);
    }
```

So at the moment I'm going through every entity in my table even those with a null twitch. To my understanding it's possible to speed up the process with indexes.

```
CREATE INDEX twitchChannel
ON Userinfo (twitchChannel)
```

So something like that would have a table with not null twitchChannel. How I loop through this table like above ?
Will it work the same way with java persistence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to:

```
SELECT ui
FROM Userinfo ui
WHERE twitchChannel IS NOT NULL
```

This will benefit from an index on `Userinfo(twitchChannel)` (assuming there really are very few values that are filled in).  At the very least, this reduces the amount of data passed from the database to the application, even if an index is not used.

Comment: But I've to specify the index like this: CREATE INDEX twitchChannel
ON Userinfo (twitchChannel) ? and it uses the index automatically ? I don't have to specify it in my query ?

Comment: @Ced . . . Yes, the query will use the index automatically.  However, the index will not always be used.  Depending on the data, 90% or 99% might have to be `NULL` for the index to be used.

Comment: thanks. Well it will be a field that my userbase will insert themselves. I doubt it will be as empty as 99% percent at least I hope not. But it doesn't really matter. Thanks.

Comment: @Ced . . . If it is the first column in the primary key (i.e. clustered index), then the query will be optimized even for greater densities of non-NULL values.

Comment: it isn't the first column. Thus maybe I gotta specify an index on it ?

Comment: @Ced . . . An index might help.  It is worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly. You have a table containing numerical id's. And you are searching the space of real numbers to see if any of those correspond to an id in your table ('twitch' id ?)

Assuming you have less than infinity users, I would have thought you can reverse this logic.

Change your query to :

```
SELECT iduserinfo FROM Userinfo ORDER BY iduserinfo
```

Then your java code will be something along the lines of :

```
   uiResult = ups.getUserInfo(id); // this executes the new query
   while (uiResult.next()) {
        twitchChannels.add(uiResult.getTwitch());   // put my twitch in an array
    }
```

(Apologies, its been a long time since I've used jdbc).

Sorry If I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: Wait, I think you misunderstood or I did. I have a table with 3 columns which are "id", "username" and "twitch". But I just thought about something like "SELECT twitch FROM Userinfo where twitch IS NOT NULL. That wasn't exactly what I was looking for but I think it'll do the trick. Thanks